# conceptual help understanding OFFSET Function and the ways in which this program outputs

Tags: assembly, x86

[image]

I am having trouble understanding the OFFSET function in the line mov esi, OFFSET var1

what does it point to? any good resources to understand how the function offset points to memory? This question is on a worksheet we are given in a class and I have the output of the function also. I am trying to see the concepts better, not for any credit, but for knowledge. The whole program is a bit confusing for me at this point in my x86 knowledge. I would appreciate help understanding that OFFSET instruction and from that I might need more help understanding how that incorporates into the rest of the problem, but little steps first! Thanks!

EDIT: I guess a pseudocode of this program might be helpful or something? I want to understand better the point of this program.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/009k3eeh.aspx) states:

```
OFFSET expression
```

Returns the offset into the relevant segment of *expression*.

Your code looks like it's written for Win32, so you're probably using the `flat` memory model. This means that you have a single 4GB segment and so for all practical purposes you can think of `OFFSET expression` as giving you the address of `expression`. In your case you're moving (copying, actually) the address of `var1` into register `esi`. The next line then increments the 32-bit doubleword starting at `var1`, which will also affect `var2` and `var3`.

Comment: thank you, that helped me see this greatly because the increment then carries over to the var 2 and var 3.

Comment: FWIW, since the value of ECX before `again:` is probably 4, I see an endless loop, or is there something I didn't see? I say "probably", because I am not sure that var3 is at offset 00000003h. But even if it isn't, I still see an endless loop.